# Direction with an apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not too good with mod_rewrite or regular expressions, but I need to ultimately use 301 redirects for a site I am moving.  The structure of the old site is as so

http://www.mywebsite.com/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm

and the new site for the same product is as so

https://www.mywebsite.com/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p.html

What I need to do is extract and remove the "/155-157" and change the extension to .html instead of .htm

So Logically I guess I would need to find the last occurrence of a "/" and the last occurrence of a "." and change the value of everything in between to "".  then the changing of the file extension is everywhere on the internet, but I don't know how I would incorporate it with the rest of it.

**edit:**
Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/[^/]*.htm$ /$1$2.html
</IfModule>
```

And here is the associated entry in my rewritelog when I tried to use it. (I just changed the ip and domain names.  I used tail and copied the entry that popped up when I tried going to the page.

```
255.255.255.255 - - [25/Apr/2012:11:57:24 --0400] [www.mywebsite.com/sid#9b25ed8][rid#9e3cc48/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/test/] pass through /var/www/test/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm
```

I added the extra /(.*) because there is an extra directory on my test page.  The structure for that is 
http://www.mywebsite.com/test/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm
to redirect to 
http://www.mywebsite.com/test/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p.html

Sorry for asking so many questions, also you can only enable rewrite logs buy going into the apache.conf or httpd.conf files and restarting the server, right?  If that is the case then I don't have the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're doing here is stripping off the last path component and then adding ".html".  So maybe something like this:

```
RewriteRule /(.*)/[^/]*.htm$ /$1.html
```

The sequence `[^/]` means "any character not a `/`", and `*` means "the previous pattern 0 or more times", so `[^/]*.htm` matches any string of non-`/` characters followed by `.htm` at the end of a string.  We discard these, use everything else, and add `.html`.

The [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) has lots of information and examples.

Comment: What does the portion "(.*)" mean?  is that just targeting .com and .net and .edu etc?  I don't think that is what it is doing but it is the only idea I can come up with.  Thanks

Comment: The `/(.*)` captures (that's what `()` does) everything else other than the last path component and assigns it to `$1`...so that we can use it on the righ-hand side of the rule.

Comment: Wait, look for any character except a newline 0 or more times, right?  Now the two are surrounded in the slashes  / (.*) / [^/]*.htm$ / $1.html  What is the purpose of having those there?  I know of a search and replace, but isn't usually prefixed with an s?  Also, the $1 in $1.html, is it just saying to take the result of the previous and append .html to it?

Comment: The slashes aren't special characters; they're just matching parts of the URL.  `$1` means "the stuff in the first set of parentheses in the left-hand side of the rule".  There is no `s/` prefix; this isn't `sed`.

Comment: Ahh ok, so www.mywebsite.com is assusumed and picks up there with matching /any characters except new lines 0 or more times (aka FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p)/something that ends in .htm (aka 155-157.htm) and then take the first part ($1) and append .html  to get (FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p.html).  Now just for educational purposes, I supposed I can use $2 to reference the second set of the rule?  With a possibility of having even 3 or 4 or more sets of the rule and referencing those as $3 or $4?

Comment: ...only if you have additional `()` delimited match groups, but yes.  So `RewriteRule /(.*)/([^/]*.htm)$ /$1.html` would put the final component in `$2` because of the additional `()` group.

Comment: Also...if this answer and subsequent discussion has been helpful, it would be great if you could mark this as an accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I got caught up with questions.  But your answers have been very helpful.  Now the final .htaccess file I came up with is as follows `code`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/[^/]*.htm$ /$1.html
</IfModule>`code`  Now it doesn't break the pages or anything, but it doesn't seem to change anything at all either.  If I put garbage in my htaccess file the page will break though, so it recognizes the htaccess to some degree.  Is this code correct or is it because something isn't enabled on the server that needs to be.

Comment: I just don't know if I need to include something else in order for it too work.

Comment: You might want to open a new question.  If you do, make sure your first enable `RewriteLog` in your configuration and post some of that so that we can see what's actually happening.  You may even spot the problem yourself.

Comment: All right, I think I'm going to go about getting it turned on by someone.

Comment: All right, I have the entry of my rewritelog when I try to use the .htaccess file.  I posted the entry and the associated .htaccess at that time in my original post under the EDIT.

Comment: I opened a new question as this one was getting long and out of scope.  Again a thanks to @larsks for giving me ideas and direction to help figure this out.  Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320029/mod-rewrite-isnt-working-as-intended