# Mod_rewrite isn't working as intended

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a specific structured url to another structure.

The original url is

http://www.mywebsite.com/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm

and I am trying to rewrite it to

http://www.mywebsite.com/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica.html

essentially removing "_p/155-157.htm" and appending .html

The htaccess file I am using to do this is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)_p/[^/]*.htm$ /$1$2.html
</IfModule>
```

But it seems to be failing,  Here is the rewrite log I get when going to the page.

```
255.255.255.255 - - [25/Apr/2012:12:34:43 --0400] [www.mywebsite.com/sid#9b25ed8][rid#9e33c28/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm -> FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm
255.255.255.255 - - [25/Apr/2012:12:34:43 --0400] [www.mywebsite.com/sid#9b25ed8][rid#9e33c28/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '/(.*)/(.*)_p/[^/]*.htm$' to uri 'FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm'
255.255.255.255 - - [25/Apr/2012:12:34:43 --0400] [www.mywebsite.com/sid#9b25ed8][rid#9e33c28/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/test/] pass through /var/www/test/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm
```

I believe it seems like something is wrong with my rule, but I'm not sure what.  If anyone can give me some thoughts, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look at this:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm -> FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm
```

That path you're matching against is actually `FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica_p/155-157.htm` because you're running inside a directory context (from a `.htaccess` file).  So it's not going to match anything starting with `/`...

That suggests that what you really want is simply...

```
RewriteRule (.*)_p/[^/]*.htm$ /$1.html
```

...if you want the result to be:

```
FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica.html
```

Comment: Okay, that works great, and for my application it is exactly what I need.  But, I happen to be testing this in a test folder, so there is an extra directory /test/FF_Supersneaker_Black_Metallica.html.  I tried to retain the /test by modifying your line to  RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)_p/[^/]*.htm$ /$1$2.html and RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)_p/[^/]*.htm$ /$1/$2.html      However it doesn't seem to take.  Any thoughts?  I'm just curious at this point in-case I needed to do something similar with an extra directory.

Comment: How about `test/(.*)_p/[^/]*.htm$` ? Generally, if you have more than one `.*` in your rule you're going to run into problems (because `.*` matches *everything*).  You could also use the `[^/]*` expression to match "everything not `/`'.

Comment: All right, Thank you for the help.  A lot of this jogged my memory from when I took perl in school.  I'm starting to get the hand of this lol.